# Find position of a cube after he undergo rotation

Tags: 3d, rotations

I have a cube with the coordinates of vertices:

```
Vet X Y Z
(top side)
V1: -0.5 0.5 0.5
V2: 0.5 0.5 0.5
V3: 0.5 0.5 -0.5
V4: -0.5 0.5 - 0.5
(bottom side)
V5: -0.5 -0.5 0.5 
V6: 0.5 -0.5 0.5
V7: 0.5 -0.5 -0.5
V8: - 0.5 -0.5 -0.5
```

After this cube suffer a rotation of 90 degrees in axis (0, 0.0). 
How do I calculate the new position of this cube?

Comment: You have to give more information in order for the rotation to be well-defined

Comment: @b00nheT I did not understand, what information? From the cube I have only the coordinates of the vertices.

Comment: axis(0,0,0) ? maybe (0,0,1) ?